# ASP.NET 5 Azure Deployment: Unable to perform the operation ("Create Directory")

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy, coreclr

This bears a lot of resemblance to [ERROR on Azure Web App Deployment of a msdeploy package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631035/error-on-azure-web-app-deployment-of-a-msdeploy-package)

I am running **msbuild /t:packagepublish** to automate deployment using ARM templates.  The relevant part of the template:

```
    "resources": [
    {
        "name": "MSDeploy",
        "type": "extensions",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webAppName'))]"
        ],
        "tags": {
            "displayName": "webDeploy"
        },
        "properties": {
            "packageUri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', parameters('webDeployPackageFolder'), '/', parameters('webDeployPackageFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
            "dbType": "None",
            "connectionString": "",
            "setParameters": {
                "IIS Web Application Name": "[variables('webAppName')]"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

This fails with the error that there is no property called "IIS Web Application Name", and I can see from the generated package file there indeed is no *parameters.xml* as there would be for an ASP.NET 4 template.

Removing that leaves me with the error:

> Unable to perform the operation ("Create Directory")  for the
>   specified directory 
>   ("C:\Users\Jim\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\API78\wwwroot").

so clearly it's trying to replicate the local directory structure.  What I'm not sure though is how/where to address this.

I see there's a msdeploy switch *-declareParam*, but I invoke ***msbuild***, not *msdeploy*.  I'd hope there's a way to do it in the template extension, but I can't find any sort of documentation on what/how to provide values there.

This is leveraging the build templates at C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its completely applicable but I recently blogged about using SetParameters via MSBuild.

https://dotnetcatch.com/2016/04/27/setparameters-via-msbuild-commandline/

Summary: The SetParams are an ItemGroup. The MSBuild.exe command doesn't support providing ItemGroups only Properties. I added some MSBuild script to accept a Property and convert to ItemGroup thus setting the params.

Comment: That looks promising.. frustrating that this 'just works' for ASP.NET 4.5; alternatively perhaps invoking msdeploy separately is the way to go.

Comment: I definitely prefer using MSDeploy separately in most cases.  This blog post was a workaround for others with the specific use case of initiating the deployment from MSBuild.